# CIDOC: Modelize political entities and their territory evolution

Tags: rdf

I recently discovered the CIDOC CRM. I have some beginner questions. How would I modelize:

1. The territory of the Mongol Empire changed from [Shapefile] to [Shapefile] in 1227.
2. The Republic of Poland was a puppet state of the Soviet Union.
3. Italy and Nazi Germany were allied during WW2.

So here's how I would do it:

#### Case 1

- One Place(E53), which has type(P2) Type(E55) called "Empire", and has Place Name(E48) "Mongol Empire"
- I can create two Space Primitives(E94), but I have no idea how to translate the information "The territory was this E94 at date1, and that E94 at date2.

#### Case 2

- Create 2 Places(E53), same as above with Type and Place Name
- How do I translate the "Puppet State" information?

#### Case 3

- I have 2 doubts here: first, how to modelize the alliance? Second, how do I say that this alliance once lasted from this date to that date.

Thanks.